# Rails 3 Admin Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to create an admin backend for a cms.

So I have a Site Model, a SitesController and a Admin:SitesController.

In /app/views/sites/show.html and in /app/views/admin/sites/index.html, new.html, etc.

**routes.rb**

```
  namespace :admin do 
    resources :sites, :except => :show
  end

  match '/:slug' => 'sites#show'
```

**EDIT**

Log output

```
Started POST "/admin/sites" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-13 19:03:12 +0200
  Processing by Admin::SitesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8IVTjl6ewasDuBEN6OgczTSdRfxSRPLmPodkrbZEKB8=", "site"=>{"title"=>"Test", "content"=>"abc", "slug"=>"home"}, "commit"=>"Create Site"}
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "sites" ("content", "created_at", "slug", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", nil], ["created_at", Wed, 13 Jul 2011 17:03:12 UTC +00:00], ["slug", nil], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 13 Jul 2011 17:03:12 UTC +00:00]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/sites
Completed 302 Found in 12ms
```

Rails doesn't create the record with the parameters from the form. Any idea?

These are the methods and the view:

**admin/sites#new**

```
  def new
    @site = Site.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end
```

**admin/sites#create**

def create
    @site = Site.new(params[:site])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @site.save
    format.html { redirect_to admin_sites_path, notice: 'Site was successfully created.' }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
  end
end
```

**admin/sites/_form**

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @site]) do |f| %>
  <% if @site.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@site.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this admin_site from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @site.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :title %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :content %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :slug %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :slug %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should redirect_to

```
 [:admin, :sites]
```

for index page

**UPD**

```
<%= form_for(@site, :url => [:admin, @site]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. The redirect_to for the sites index is working. And if there is no record in the database, the index page is displayed without an error. As soon as I'm creating a record, the error is displayed.

Rails doesn't save the parameters from the form. Every field in the database is set to nil... Any idea why?

Comment: You don't understand, ok. What is `@admin_sites`? And where should `redirect_to [:admin, @admin_sites]` redirect?

Comment: @admin_sites is just the variable for the site. I have changed redirect_to admin_sites_path. That worked, because I don't need to redirect to the show view.

Comment: @Daniel, pluralised `@admin_sites` is variable for one site? cool. And `redirect_to admin_sites_path` is just the same as `redirect_to [:admin, :sites]`. So I still don't understand your problem.

Comment: Redirect isn't the problem. The problem is, that the site isn't created with the parameters from the form. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Run `rake routes` to see your routes.

If you used scaffolding you probably have code like `redirect_to @site` and `redirect_to sites_path` in your Admin::SitesController.  You'll need to go through and change those to the appropriate named routes, e.g. `redirect_to admin_site_path(@site)` and `admin_sites_path`.

Comment: Helped with the redirect after the record of a site is created. But the problem now is, that the parameters from the form aren't saved in the database, every field in the db is nil.

Comment: If you are using `attr_accessible` on your model be sure to include the fields you want: `attr_accessible :content, :slug, :title`

Answer (score 0):

Your create form should be built like this:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @site] do |f| %>
  // form fields go here
<% end %>
```

This will create a form that posts to Admin::SitesController#create **unless your index view or controller action set `@site` to an existing record instead of `@site = Site.new`**. If you are setting `@site` to an existing record, than that would change the form_for to PUT to the update action, and when you have `form_for @site ...` instead of `form_for [:admin, @site]`, that will send it to SitesController instead of Admin::SitesController. The error you are providing looks like you've made both of these mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your respond =D
Unfortunately that wasn't the mistakes. I've updated the question. The output from the log tells that it goes to the create method.

Comment: In the question you are now showing a completely different error than the one you had when I answered the question (something to the effect of no "update" action in SitesController"). If one problem is solved and you have a follow-up problem, then you should ask a separate question.